# Custom AuthorizeFilter: How to add filter to check client ip or authorize to identityserver

Tags: c#, authorization, identityserver4, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize-attribute

I am developing a net core 2.2 web api. 
I have setup authorization through identityserver, and works fine. 
Now a like to put the api behind azure api management, and like to add api management ip-address to whitelist, so if the request is from api management, I will not authorize through identityserver.

What I like to to, is to add a custom authorize filter, to check for client ip, and if ip is valid, I will not do authorize through identityserver, but if the ip is not valid, I will try to authorize through identityserver.

I like to override this AuthorizeFilter. Someone has any tips?

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    if (!_env.IsUnitTest())
    {
        //Add global filter to make sure we require authenticated users for everything!
       var requireAuthenticatedUsersPolicy =
           new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
       options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(requireAuthenticatedUsersPolicy));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Action filters to check the remote IP address of requests for specific controllers or action methods. The entire code sample is in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/ip-safelist?view=aspnetcore-2.2) :

```
public class ClientIdCheckFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private readonly string _safelist;

    public ClientIdCheckFilter
        (ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("ClientIdCheckFilter");
        _safelist = configuration["AdminSafeList"];
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"Remote IpAddress: {context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress}");

        var remoteIp = context.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        _logger.LogDebug($"Request from Remote IP address: {remoteIp}");

        string[] ip = _safelist.Split(';');

        var bytes = remoteIp.GetAddressBytes();
        var badIp = true;
        foreach (var address in ip)
        {
            var testIp = IPAddress.Parse(address);
            if (testIp.GetAddressBytes().SequenceEqual(bytes))
            {
                badIp = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (badIp)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation(
                $"Forbidden Request from Remote IP address: {remoteIp}");
            context.Result = new StatusCodeResult(401);
            return;
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
I got this working with adding a Requirement and Handler:

```
public class IpAddressWhitelistHandler : AuthorizationHandler<IpAddressWhitelistRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpAccessor;

    public IpAddressWhitelistHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpAccessor)
    {
        _httpAccessor = httpAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, IpAddressWhitelistRequirement requirement)
    {
        var remoteIp = _httpAccessor.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress;
        if (IsIpValid(remoteIp, requirement))
        {
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        else
        {
            if (IsAuthenticated(context.User))
            {
                context.Succeed(requirement);
            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            }
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }

    private bool IsIpValid(IPAddress ipAddress, IpAddressWhitelistRequirement requirement)
    {
        bool validIp = false;

        var bytes = ipAddress.GetAddressBytes();

        var safeIp = IPAddress.Parse(requirement.IpAddress);
        if (safeIp.GetAddressBytes().SequenceEqual(bytes))
        {
            validIp = true;
        }

        return validIp;
    }

    private bool IsAuthenticated(ClaimsPrincipal user)
    {
        var userIsAnonymous = user?.Identity == null || !user.Identities.Any(i => i.IsAuthenticated);

        return !userIsAnonymous;

    }
}

public class IpAddressWhitelistRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public string IpAddress { get; set; }
}
```